# Julia - n-nested loops

Tags: macros, combinations, julia, nested-loops, cartesian

Im trying to make a n-nested loop method in Julia

```
function fun(n::Int64)
    @nloops n i d->1:3 begin\n
        @nexprs n j->(print(i_j))\n
    end
end
```

But the @nloops definition is limited to

```
_nloops(::Int64, ::Symbol, ::Expr, ::Expr...)
```

and I get the error

```
_nloops(::Symbol, ::Symbol, ::Expr, ::Expr)
```

Is there any way to make this work? Any help greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**

What I ended up doing was using the combinations method

For my problem, I needed to get all k-combinations of indices to pull values from an array, so the loops would had to look like

```
for i_1 in 1:100
    for i_2 in i_1:100
        ...
           for i_k in i_[k-1]:100
```

Comment: Got exactly the same question :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of loops needs to be a compile-time constant – a numeric literal, in fact: the code generated for the function body cannot depend on a function argument. Julia's generated functions won't help either since `n` is just a plain value and not part of the type of any argument. Your best bet for having the number of nested loops depend on a runtime value like `n` is to use recursion.

Answer (score 5):

In julia-0.4 and above, you can now do this:

```
function fun(n::Int)
    for I in CartesianRange(ntuple(d->1:3, n))
        @show I
    end
end
```

In most cases you don't need the Base.Cartesian macros anymore (although there are still some exceptions). It's worth noting that, just as described in StefanKarpinski's answer, this loop will not be "type stable" because `n` is not a compile-time constant; if performance matters, you can use the "function barrier technique." See http://julialang.org/blog/2016/02/iteration for more information about all topics related to these matters.